# Web application (Elastic Beanstalk + Flask) reading from DynamoDB more than expected

Tags: flask, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm new to web development in general. I set up a flask application with elastic beanstalk that queries a dynamodb table. When I run the application locally, I can see the ConsumedReadCapacityUnits spike to ~128 and then go back down. Presumably this represents one query of the table. However, when I deploy the application as an application to elastic beanstalk, the ConsumedReadCapacityUnits spikes up to 400-800 ConsumedReadCapacityUnits and stays there, even when I don't think anybody is loading the app. Why does this happen? Is elastic beanstalk constantly querying the table? Is there a way to make it not?

**Code:** https://github.com/kimberlymcm/flaskapp/

**Function for querying the table**

```
import boto3  
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key  

dynamo_client = boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name='us-west-2')  

def get_data(items=["pm1", "pm25", "pm10"]):  
    cols_to_extract = f"device_id, #time_taken"  
    for item in items:  
        cols_to_extract += f", payload.{item}"  
    response = dynamo_client.query(  
        ProjectionExpression=cols_to_extract,  
        ExpressionAttributeNames={"#time_taken": "time"},  
        KeyConditionExpression="device_id = :enviro",  
        ExpressionAttributeValues={":enviro" : {"S" : "enviro"}},  
        TableName='iot_table')  
    return response['Items']
```

The left of this graph is when the app is running only in elastic beanstalk and I'm not loading the app. The right is when it is running locally.
[image]

Comment: Do you have any requests coming to your EB app from the internet that would be triggering the read operations? What about some health checkes? Mayeb R53 or ALB healtchecks keep triggering it?

Comment: How would I check if it is one of those things? I'm having troubling figuring out where the requests are coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the automated load balancer. I had just gone with the default configuration for Elastic Beanstalk, which apparently included a load balancer. I guess the load balancer health check was sending requests to the database (?). When I removed the load balancer, traffic went back down to expected levels.

I checked the route 53 console as well, but I didn't have any health checks set up.